# Dual boot with Endless OS

Tags: dual-boot

I bought Acer Aspire 3 pre-installed with [Endless OS](https://endlessos.com/). It seems this OS is installed on OSTree which is read only file system. Is there any way to install Ubuntu in dual boot with Endless OS.

Comment: [OSTree isn't a filesystem. It's only a way to install read-only sets of files to whatever filesystem.](https://ostree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/introduction/) I assume you can resize the Endless OS partition using GParted on a Live DVD/USB. Then, you can boot into Endless OS to make sure it's still OK. Then, you can use the free space to install Ubuntu. If Endless OS has a swap partition, make sure to tell the Ubuntu installer to also use that partition for swap (but not to format the swap partition).

Comment: Perhaps I can resize the partition and install Ubuntu. I can create a swap file on the Ubuntu partition but if I install Grub it won't detect Endless OS and I may lose the Grub of Endless OS. If I install Ubuntu without its Grub I can't add Ubuntu boot entry into the Grub of Endless OS. The problem is with the Grub used by Endless OS which is not editable.

Comment: You might be able to copy the GRUB configuration in Endless OS to a USB drive or something and then try seeing if you can merge it manually into Ubuntu's GRUB configuration with a text editor (so that Ubuntu's ends up with both). If Ubuntu's GRUB understands the configuration syntax and settings (which is somewhat likely unless they've significantly modified GRUB), it might work. There also might be some sort of chain-loading thing you might be able to do where one GRUB loads another, though I'm not sure if that's possible or how.

Comment: Yes I can read the grub.cfg of Endless OS while working in Endless OS and copy it to internet, then read it while on Ubuntu on USB boot and write it in 40_custom file and update grub. I know all that. Unfortunately Ubuntu Grub won't be allowed to boot Endless OS from those entries due to whole system being on OSTree.

Comment: Endless OS allows dual boot with pre-installed Windows 10. The details are on this page https://support.endlessm.com/hc/en-us/articles/214369366--What-changes-are-made-to-my-system-by-the-Installer-?mobile_site=true and this page https://support.endlessm.com/hc/en-us/articles/212890106-How-do-I-install-Endless-OS-alongside-Windows-?mobile_site=true If we can introduce similar entry for Ubuntu on Windows 10 on c:/ drive perhaps there can be triple boot of Windows 10, Endless OS and Ubuntu. Please examine.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 in my Endless VM by booting the ISO, reducing the size of the endless partition and creating a new root partition for Ubuntu.

Once booted in Ubuntu I added the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and ran `sudo update-grub`:

```
menuentry "Endless" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1 1234-abcd
    else
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1234-abcd
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/endless/shim.efi
}
```

You should replace every instance of `1234-abcd` with the UUID displayed in Gnome Disks for the EFI System partition (which is usually the first FAT formatted partition on UEFI systems).

I can boot both systems now. If you have any issues it may be related to secure boot being active. You actually don't need to modify or create new entries in Grub when you can mange which efi binary to boot from the EFI System partition either through the firmware ("BIOS" setup utility) or efibootmgr in Linux.

Edit: I expected that os-prober would detect the mounted endless partition and automatically created the respective menu entries, it did not.

Comment: I am out of station till Nov 10 2018 and don't have the new Acer Aspire with Endless OS bought recently. I can try your suggestion when I reach home. My question at the moment is "are we trying to chainload the grub of Endless OS from the grub installed by Ubuntu?"

Comment: Yes the example menu code does chainloading (`chainloader /EFI/endless/shim.efi`). If the Acer BIOS provides an option to manage and setup these UEFI NVRAM entries to tell the BIOS to boot the respective OS directly without involving GRUB chainloading then that would be even better and easier.

Comment: I have another hard disk in USB casing with multiple Ubuntu installations and Windows XP. I edited the /etc/grub.d/40_custom inserting the above menuentry with UUID of sda1. I could not chainload the grub on the main disk even after disabling secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

I could chainload the grub of Endless OS with the below entry in /etc/grub.d/40_custom suggested by LiveWireBT
To display the grub entries of Ubuntu I had to change following lines in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Uncomment the line GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden by putting hash sign and changed the GRUB_TIMEOUT to 10.

I had to disable secure boot to boot Endless OS, although, Endless OS boots with secure boot "on" if I boot directly with grub of Endless OS.

Anyway now I have Ubuntu 18.04 in Dual Boot with Endless OS.

Answer (score 0):

I've dualbooted Endless OS with Elementary OS. Actually multibooted. I also have bunch of other OSes.

What I've done it installing endless os on a separate disk first. Then shrink it to desired size, make room to the make disk I want to have endless os on, then using gparted to copy the endless `ostree` partition and paste on the freespace I made on main disk

You need to make the partition label of endless os as `ostree` because that's the label Endless Oss' `/etc/fstab` file uses. Also copy the efi files from Endless' disk to main disk.

Now shutdown, unplug the endless os disk, start OS, chainload endless os `shim.efi` or `grubx64.efi` to boot from existing Grub.